# Make "stop-button" instead "start-button"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Good afternoon. I started to study android studio and decided to create an app "trafficlight".  It should change the colour every 2 seconds and while colour changing, start-button should change on stop-button. And that's the problem. I watched video and wrote the similar code, but nothing happends :(. If it isn't difficult for you please check my code and give me advice how can I improve :).
Here's my code:

xml of main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Balb1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
        android:background="@color/Grey"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Balb2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#ACA5A5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Balb3"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Balb3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#ACA5A5"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Balb1">

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Balb2" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here's the code:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements onClick {

    private LinearLayout B1, B2, B3;
    private Button button1;
    private boolean startOrStop = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        B1 = findViewById(R.id.Balb1);
        B2 = findViewById(R.id.Balb2);
        B3 = findViewById(R.id.Balb3);
        button1 = findViewById(R.id.startButton);
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view){

        if(!startOrStop) {
            button1.setText(getString(R.string.stop));
            startOrStop = true;

            new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
                while (startOrStop){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
        }

        else {
            startOrStop = false;
            button1.setText(getString(R.string.start));
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        startOrStop = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the following code:

```
new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
            while (startOrStop){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

your while is run infinitely because within loop there is no logic to false the startOrStop variable. It also blocks the UI thread.

So you should write some logic for making that startOrStop variable to false within loop.
Otherwise you didn't need any while loop here it dose nothing simple wrote the following code it will work.

```
new Thread((Runnable) () -> {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Ok I understood, but it still not working even with this code :(

Comment: Add onclick attribute in the above xml tag Button and write the function name.

Comment: Like this

<Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:text="Start"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Balb2"
        android:onClick="onClickStart"
 />

Comment: Thank you very much!. Now everithing is working!

Comment: @Cross Welcome my pleasure!